# Restrict answers to n thousand characters or less

Tags: discussion

Stackoverflow is a question and answer website. However, at times I notice answers that look more like a tutorial, article or blog post. I have the following issues with long answers:

1. At times, such answers do not fit the question-answer model
2. Long answers obscure shorter, to-the-point answers below them
3. Long answers get more votes simply because people tend to reward the effort without reading the answer completely
4. Finally, if the question warrants a lengthy answer then the question itself could be considered "too broad"

If others agree with me then what should we do about such answers? I think we should mark both question and answers as community wiki; then others could just edit the long answers instead of posting new answers that would otherwise remain unnoticed.

Comment: Hmm, it is already hard enough to get rid of crap that nobody likes.  Maybe the goal of getting rid of crap that everybody likes shouldn't be our primary focus.  Everybody has one vote, use yours the way you see fit.  And if that's not enough to get rid of content that you don't like then so be it.  Posting better content is then your only true recourse.

Comment: Why don't we just restrict it to 140 charecters or less? That way people with no attention span whatsoever can get answers too

Comment: [72 charachters](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qcmzP.png) can take a lot of actual screen space...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do have a point when it come to *super* long answers sometimes being a hallmark of a problematic question; if a question requires an *essay length* answer, then it could conceivably be asking for more ground to be covered than Q&A was designed to facilitate. *Sometimes*.

But, you lose me after that. A good number of the *best* answers we have on the site contain no less than three self-contained sections of code that can be compiled and run so that folks can learn about three different ways of approaching a problem. I would *not* want to prevent that, or take away any extrinsic motivation to write such answers.

Then, you have canonical posts - posts that go *very* deep into questions that tend to be asked in infinite repetition. While many of these are community wiki so that they can be maintained by a greater number of people, their length doesn't necessarily put them at a disadvantage as they tend to be sectioned quite well and easy to parse.

If you feel that an answer is unnecessarily long, tell the author how it could be much shorter while conveying the same information and points even better through succinctness. If you find an answer so difficult to read that it's unhelpful, and you're certain that it's not simply an aversion to reading at play, then use your votes to indicate as such.

We're not going to force people to work in *that* tight of a space, because far too often the limits that we *do* have (15 times as high) can barely contain the awesomeness that some folks tend to write *on a very consistent basis*.

Comment: "Then, you have canonical posts - posts that go *very* deep into questions that tend to be asked in infinite repetition." Even the *narrowest* of these repetitive questions can have answers covering them just as deeply and thoroughly. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107) for example, which for more than *8 kilobytes* answers the question "how to select the first child with a class".